# How to force a WinForms control to fill up FlowLayoutPanel that's in a multi-column-spanning cell in a TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: winforms, f#, tablelayoutpanel, flowlayoutpanel

I have a `TextBox` that's in a `FlowLayoutPanel` that's inside a cell of a `TableLayoutPanel`. The `FlowLayoutPanel` spans 5 columns of the `TableLayoutPanel` and fills up the entire width of the 5 columns. However, the `TextBox` doesn't fill up the entire width of the `FlowLayoutPanel`, as you can see here (the black border is the `FlowLayoutPanel`):

[image: Test table layout panel]

How can I get the `TextBox` to span the entire width of the `FlowLayoutPanel`?

Code to produce this example:

```
// fsi --exec Test.fsx
open System
open System.Windows.Forms

let frmMain () =
  let f = new Form(Text = "Test table layout panel")
  let tlp =
    new TableLayoutPanel
      ( ColumnCount = 5,
        RowCount = 1,
        AutoSize = true,
        Parent = f )
  let flp =
    new FlowLayoutPanel
      ( AutoSize = true,
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle )
  let tb = new TextBox(Parent = flp)

  tlp.Controls.Add(flp, 0, 0)
  tlp.SetColumnSpan(flp, 5)
  flp.Dock <- DockStyle.Fill
  tb.Dock <- DockStyle.Fill

  f

[<STAThread>]
do
  Application.EnableVisualStyles()
  Application.Run(frmMain ())
```

Comment: Your TextBox needs to be MultiLine = true.  Docking the TextBox to Fill won't work with the FlowLayoutPanel.  Doesn't make sense.  That FlowLayoutPanel should just be a panel in that case.

Comment: Did you try setting the `TextBox` height and width to the `FlowLayoutPanel`'s height and width? I'm not into F# but by based on the code snippet the `TextBox` height and width should set exclusively.

Comment: @LarsTech - OK! So making it a `Panel` instead of a `FlowLayoutPanel` and setting the `Dock` to `Fill` does solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @fujiFX - thanks, it looks like `Panel` is the right control for this job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Docking doesn't work inside a FlowLayoutPanel since it wants to layout the controls in a flowing order.  Since you want to dock-fill the TextBox control, try using a simple Panel control instead.

Also, set the Multiline property of the TextBox to true.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really `Dock` inside a flow layout panel, it makes no sense.

A flow layout panel is used to contain a collection of controls that flow together (left to right, top to bottom), having one control fill it will negate the usefulness of the flow layout.

If you want to fill the columns with a text box, just use a `Textbox` with a `Dock Fill` and `Multiline` set to `true`

Comment: I did a little research just now. Turns out you can dock and anchor inside a `FlowLayoutPanel`, which will lay out the controls according to a specific logic: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171633%28v=vs.90%29.aspx